# URL Connection - no connection

Tags: android, mysql, http, url, connection

I want to connect to a URL and disconnect after that. But after my Update on Android 4.1 (worked before on 2.3.7) it doesn't work anymore! :/

Why? I have no Idea:

```
public void insert_into_Mysql() {
    URL url = new URL("http://***/insertOrder.php?product="+product+"&owner="+owner);
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    try {
        openActivityOverview(product);  
    } finally {
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
```

Noting is inserted in the MySql-Table...

Thanks for Help! :)

Comment: Android 3.0, It is not legal to open a url connection in the main UI Thread. You MUST do this in an AsyncTask. or create new thread and use thread .run

Comment: Thanks! But I do not find any way how I can do ist. I googled many but nothing worked! Does anybody know how I have to do it? :)

Answer (score 2):

write url connection in thread.

From Android API v15, it requires no heavy process working on main thread. So you should move your logic to another thread like bellow source code:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
        // your logic
   }                        
}).start();
```

More information please refer http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/responsiveness.html

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)
to open url connection.

Refer below links for example :

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html

http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/03/17/understanding-asynctask-once-and-forever/

Answer (score 1):

You can use AsyncTask to perform background operations such as networking.

```
private class ATask extends AsyncTask
{

    public ATask()
    {
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) 
    {
        // Background logic here.
        return null;
    }   

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object result) 
    {
        // Foreground logic here.
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can disable the no networking on mainthread restriction, but this is generally considered a bad idea, and probably should not be used outside of playing around.

StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);